# /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied

Tags: centos, docker

I tried to run [this docker image](https://github.com/bgruening/docker-galaxy-stable) which load inside another image. However, I run into `/var/run/docker.sock: permission denied` on CentOS 6.6 and docker 1.7.1 which I reported [here](https://github.com/bgruening/docker-galaxy-stable/issues/87#issuecomment-1349537567).

Which linux distribution support docker-in-docker images?

Comment: Is `selinux` on your host in enforcing mode (`getenforce`)?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, due to selinux. You can check if selinux is the culprit by:

1. Disabling selinux: `setenforce 0`
2. Retrying

If disabling selinux solved your problem, it's not a reason to leave it disabled:

1. Enable selinux: `setenforce 1`
2. Allow the socket connection in the selinux configuration: `setsebool docker_connect_any true`
3. Run your Docker container with the `--priviledged` option

Answer (score -3):

Try changing selinux on the CentOS host to permissive:

```
setenforce 0
```

This worked for me.